# Visualforce, Controller, and Standard Object

Tags: visualforce, controller, object

(1) I have a Visualforce page that receives 5 inputs.

(2) I have an Apex controller that takes these 5 inputs and posts them directly to Chatter.

(3) Question: I have a separate custom object with 5 fields. I'd like these 5 fields to populate with the information a user enters into the VF page so that a record can be captured on this object. How would I go about this? A trigger?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something you can do entirely with the Standard Controller for your object. You'd create a new visualforce page that uses `<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c">` and later a `<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>`. And of course, some `<apex:inputField>`s for each of your five fields.

The VF Dev Guide is a great resource for learning the standard controller. Check out https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_associate.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_actions.htm

Comment: I haven't been able to make this method work. I need the actual field values to post to chatter, and not a link to the record. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing (attempting to do):

Comment: see added code above